# USB File System: Unknown. GParted

Tags: usb, gparted

I have an 8GB Flash disk (I don't know the exact model).
I deleted partitions in GParted, and now it doesn't work. When I want to format the device, it says that "dev/sdb close device failed input/output error"

P.S I cant format disk "Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error"

Output of `sudo parted -l /dev/sdb`:

```
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? retry                                                       
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? retry                                                       
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? retry                                                       
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? ignore                                                      
Model: Generic Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 8389MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  8389MB  8388MB  primary
```

Comment: Did you just delete the partitions or create a new one? If not, do it and use FAT32 as file system to format.

Comment: it says "Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error"

Comment: So is there any partition created or not? Could you please post the output of `sudo parted -l /dev/sdb` as an edit to your question (use code formatting)?

Comment: no.. i think i just delete partition

Comment: But there seems to be a partition, just no file system. Can you test whether you can access the device from another computer or at least a live system? I believe the device is defect, but that would be something you could try to check. Btw I removed some passages that have nothing to do with your USB device.

Comment: I checked it on another notebook with win8, and it asks "format disk?", in property: size:0

Comment: And if you format it with Win8, does it give you errors? As there is no data on the device, there is nothing you can hurt, as it might be physically defect anyway. Just don't format anything else than the stick.

Comment: i cant format - error, too. no i think it does not physical defect, because error happend when I made LiveUSB from this disk, and I think that it was error in process

Comment: @Set-xx: ByteCommander asked me to help on this one.  **Warning** the utility `dd` also known as `d`isk `d`estroyer must be used with caution.  Therefore the following command will output 0's on only the first 8192 MB although your USB flash drive can contain 8389MB...  Copy-paste therefore the following command in a terminal and verify  3 times you've got the correct command!  `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=8192`

Comment: You have to run the dd command with sudo to get root permissions. So type `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=8192`

Comment: @Fabby yes, i use SUDO. dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdb’: No space left on device
2884+0 records in
2883+0 records out
3023728640 bytes (3.0 GB) copied, 0.822732 s, 3.7 GB/s

Comment: @Fabby have u some ideas? or this is end of my flash disk?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a faulty hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Your USB stick definitely has a physical defect, so you have to go and replace it.

It looks like a memory cell at some position around 3GB has died. This is not repairable at all (especially not by software)! You can see this because the dd command you used should just write 00h (all bits to zero) to every memory cell on your device, without caring about partitions or file systems. As this did not work, the error is beyond any partitioning and formatting stuff and therefore seems to be hardware.
Sorry for having to say this, but your stick is ready for the dustbin.

Comment: ok, thank u for help. You say that 3GB has died, it's mean that i can use 5GB? or not

Comment: No. You can not just tell the stick to leave out some specific memory cells and use only the others (as far as I know). There is a built-in controller (flash translation layer) that automatically takes care of all cells being used about the same amount. This is needed because flash cells die after a specific number of writing cycles. The problem is that logical memory addresses are not statically mapped to physical memory cells, but dynamically assigned by the (not properly working?) controller. Therefore it is impossible to say we just use the last 5GB, as they can get located everywhere.

Comment: @Set-xx: this is a USB stick, not a hard drive.  Hard drives can mark sectors as bad so die a horrible slow death (like cancer) but SDDs and USB sticks suddenly develop errors at a tremendous rates (like a heart-attack): For more background info, read this article: http://eprints.unife.it/715/1/Tesi%20Dottorato%20Zambelli.pdf  (After that, you'll understand why we tell you to just throw it away)